# How to use scrollbar in react swiper?

Tags: swiper.js

scroll indicator is not showing. am i missing something here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-gagarin-8k3co?file=/src/App.js

I was comparing DOM with the example in js

https://swiperjs.com/demos/080-scrollbar.html

where scrollbar looks like this:

```
<div class="swiper-scrollbar" style="opacity: 0; transition: all 400ms ease 0s;"><div class="swiper-scrollbar-drag" style="transform: translate3d(751.8px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0ms ease 0s; width: 107.4px;"></div></div>
```

and in my react app i have just

```
<div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
```

and no *swiper-scrollbar-drag* element

Answer (score 1):

got it. forgot to install additional components

```
import SwiperCore, { Scrollbar } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
SwiperCore.use([Scrollbar]);
```